# Why my command prompt inside of my visual studio code is not working

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I'm recently learning django, and I learned that I need to use pipenv to not install django globally. So I firstly installed pipenv, and I made a cmd(command prompt) inside of my visual studio code(I'm working in visual studio code and I'm windows user). When I hit `pipenv --three` at cmd inside of the vscode to make a virtual environment, and cmd inside of the vscode said `command not found`. In contrast, when I hit `pipenv --three` at cmd outside of the vscode, it seemed it worked properly. Why is it happening?

Also, I hit `pipenv shell` and installed django, but when I hit `django-admin` to check if django installed properly, it also didn't work like `pipenv --three` command hit inside of the vscode cmd.

Ask me if you didn't understand my situation, and thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide us with a screenshot of the VSCode terminal so that we can check the relevant factors and help you better? In addition, what is the Python environment you are currently using in VSCode?

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I temporarily solved that problem by giving the full filepath of pipenv.py. And bit hilariously, I don't know how to get the error above again, so unfortunately, I'm not able to provide you a screenshot or etc. But I'm very grateful for your comment to help me :)